# How to solve ODE $\epsilon^2 v''-v=-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an IVP $$\epsilon^2 v''-v=-1$$ over interval $(0,1)$ with $v(0)=0$ and $v(1)=1$, and $\epsilon>0$ is a constant.

I know how to solve 
$$
\epsilon^2 v'' -v =0
$$
but I got stuck on how to have the particular solution$$\epsilon^2 v''-v=-1$$

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: That's actually a BVP, not an IVP. Anyway, a good trick: if you have an $n$th order linear ODE with constant coefficients, and the forcing is a polynomial of degree $m$, then a particular solution is a polynomial of degree at most $n+m$. So in your case a particular solution is a polynomial of degree at most $2$. (In fact I think in this case it can be degree $0$).

Comment: I assume you know jow to find the complementary function? use $\nu=\lambda$ as a particular integral...

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can take the general solution $v_h$ you found to
$$
\epsilon^2v''-v=0
$$
and add the constant solution $v_p=1$ to it. The reason is that $v_p=1$ is *one* solution to
$$
\epsilon^2v''-v=-1
$$
and the theory on linear differential equations then says that you get the *general solution* to the non-homogeneous differential equation as the *sum* of the general solution to the homogeneous differential equation and *one* solution to the non-homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: Yea, but I have $v(0)=0$ which exclude the constant solution $v_p\equiv1$...

Comment: You should match with boundary conditions on the function $v_h+v_p$, not on $v_p$ only, i.e. you have $v(x)=Ae^{x/\epsilon}+Be^{-x/\epsilon}+1$. Then match with your conditions $v(0)=0$ and $v(1)=1$ to get $A$ and $B$.